# I used Yeoman to create a VS Code extension. Which version of Electron am I using?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, electron-builder

I need to use electron-rebuild for a module that I am using in the extension. The error message after attempting to run .\node_modules.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd is,

> An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild Unable to find
>   electron's version number, either install it or specify an explicit
>   version
>
> Error: Unable to find electron's version number, either install it or
>   specify an explicit version

but I don't know how to find the correct value for the version since I did not install electron manually (Yeoman and the code template took care of this, I assume). An Electron reference doesn't appear to be in either package file.

I would like to know how to go about using electron-rebuild in the Yeoman generated VS Code extension?